# How does one calculate the Fourier transform of the correlation function for the ferromagnet?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, fourier-transform, critical-phenomena

I'm working through Huang's book and in chapter 16, it discusses the correlation function of the ferromagnet and its Fourier transform. In (16.8), the book states that

$$\Gamma(\vec{r}) = \langle m(\vec{r}) m(0)\rangle - \langle m(\vec{r}) \rangle\langle m(0)\rangle.$$

It then states that the Fourier transform and inverse Fourier transforms of $m$ and $\widetilde{m}$ are

$m(\vec{r}) = \int\frac{d^3k}{(2 \pi)^3} e^{i\vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}} \tilde{m}(\vec{k}) $

$\tilde{m}(\vec{k}) = \int d^3 x e^{-i\vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}} m(\vec{r})$

And using these you should be able to get, from taking the Fourier transform of each side of the first equation,

$\tilde{\Gamma}(\vec{k}) = \langle\tilde{m}(\vec{k})m(0)\rangle - \langle m(0)\rangle^2(2 \pi)^3 \delta(\vec{k})$

I'm not sure how to get this final equation. I believe the $\langle m(0)\rangle^2$ term in the right side comes because of spatial invariance but outside of this I'm not sure how we arrive at this Fourier transform. If anybody can write out the derivation or a few hints, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: He probably assumes that $\langle m\rangle$ means integral of m over all space divided by volume of that space. This means the function $\tilde \Gamma(k)$ is integral of an integral. Did you try to re-express this integral of integral by changing order of integrations?

Comment: Do you know that $\mathcal{F}\{1\}\propto \delta(\vec k)$? Please explicitly state how the averaging is defined. Also, please add the full title of the book.